# Remote Render Monitoring

Tags: python, blender-internal-render-engine

I've never used Blender before but I need to make a web page to monitor for render. I was thinking about a little software in Python  that runs into each PC which is rendering. This software should read some data from blender like:

- Project name
- Current Frame
- Time remaining
- GPU usage
- List of GPUs

and it should write them into a file or send them somewhere through the network.
I need help to understand how to get these datas(and probably more) from Blender

Thank you!

Comment: Hello and welcome. What have you got so far? What part are you stuck with? As it stands it this question sounds too broad

Comment: HI! Yes I'm just at the begin and I want to understand how to get data from Blender before start. Is there a guide that can introduce me to communicate with Blender? It would be great to understand how get certain data from Blender during a render. Are they stored in a file somewhere? Do I need to "ask" this info with a POST? a Socket?

Comment: You can look into the Python API reference https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79 if there's a way it will be there